# Caculating the percentage of respondents who answered yes to multiple questions

Tags: excel, combinations, percentage, survey

I have survey result data in an excel sheet. The column headings are locations where respondents were willing to travel for work (11 total locations/columns) - they had to select yes or no for each location. What I want to know is what percentage of people who said yes to one were willing to travel to another, i.e., 20% of people who selected Chicago are also willing to go to Denver. There is no logical way to sort the responses, as they appear very random.

People picked between 1 and 11 yeses. I'd like to run all the combinations.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, try to add example data, so we can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this ..

[image]

For Cell B12 Formula `=COUNTIF(B2:B11;"=yes")` .. copy it to right

For Cell B13 Formula `=ROUND(B12/SUM($B$12:$L$12)*100;2)` .. copy it to right

Hope this help ...

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to guess what is the required output. Anyway here is my understanding. For all combination of 2 cities get percentage of 2 "Yes"es, i.e.: What percentage of respondents entered "Yes" for City1 and City2.

First, convert "Yes"es to 1, and blanks to 0. Simple enough `=IF(YourCell="Yes",1,0)` and you should get the first table in the image below.

Second, create a matrix of Cities, and enter following to `C15` and copy it to all cells in the matrix.

`=SUMPRODUCT(OFFSET($B$2:$B$11,0,$A15),B$2:B$11)/10`

Change the `10` in the above formula to total number of Persons.

It is possible to merge these 2 steps into one, but might get ugly.

[image]